# System logging for monitoring an AngularFire (JavaScript/noBackend) app?

Tags: security, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

Hello I'm building an AngularFire app and I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to securely monitor and record if...

- There was a failed attempt to login
- A failed write/read
- HTTP Requests/Responses

Can write this code in javascript? Wouldn't a malicious user just be able to change the code so I won't be able see certain log messages?

What solutions have people been doing to make sure this kind of functionality is secure?

Is it possible to write a security rule saying if you do any sort of activity on the app, that it needs to have a log message attached to it?

I know nothing is bulletproof, it would be nice though to hear what secure solutions people have come up with. THANKS!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the `angularFireAuth` service to implement some kind of authentication for your users (http://angularfire.com/documentation.html#authentication). Once a user authenticates to Firebase, you can write some rules in Firebase Forge to determine what locations they are allowed to read and write. The security documentation will help in crafting those rules: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security-quickstart.html

This prevents someone from reading or writing data in Firebase without authenticating first. You can implement your own login scheme, or use one of the built-in "Simple Login" providers, which are Facebook, Github, Twitter and Persona (https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html).

Comment: Sorry that doesn't really answer my question. Im not looking for authentication. You guys made that really easy to do. I'm looking for a way to do system logging for monitoring.

Comment: Have you ever used Drupal? Like the dblog module.

Comment: You can use the security rules to enforce that any time a user tries to write data, they also write a log message.

Comment: Great! So I can do this client-side. Thank you.